# Como efetivamente remover a metatag refresh de uma página?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Últimamente eu tenho acessado vários sites de notícias que utilizam esta metatag para atualizar suas páginas de tempos em tempos:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="300">
```

Eu entendo o motivo do uso dela por parte dos sites, mas com o tempo essa funcionalidade se torna bastante irritante para o usuário. Foi aí que eu tive a idéia de criar uma extensão para o Chrome que removesse essa tag quando o usuário assim quisesse. Mas o que acontece é que mesmo removendo ela do DOM, depois do determinado número de segundos a página sofre o refresh da mesma forma.

Então minha pergunta é:

**Existe alguma forma de remover ou desabilitar efetivamente o funcionamento desta metatag com javascript / jquery?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É possível, ainda que por meio de um truque: parar o redirecionamento não é possível, mas você pode cancelar ele fazendo, no momento que a página for recarregar, a página redirecionar para um endereço que retorne `HTTP 204`.

Caso queira uma extensão que faça isso use essa (a explicação acima é a descrição da extensão):
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stop-autorefresh/lcldcllmbokpbniijpnkpgoboadbfphb

Answer (score 1):

Só vejo uma abordagem, seu script deve recarregar a página toda removendo o meta refresh.

Busca por [Ajax](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/) o Conteúdo da página.

Abre ([open](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_open.asp)) o documento

```
window.document.open();
```

Grava o novo conteúdo ([write](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_write.asp)) sem o meta refresh, use [replace](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp)

```
window.document.write(NOVO_HTML.replace(/<meta http-equiv="refresh".*\/?>/gi, ""));
```

Depois fecha ([close](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_close.asp)) o document

```
window.document.close();
```

Talvez seja necessário colocar o conteúdo em uma nova janela pois a inicial já está com o meta para disparar.

Bons testes.

Answer (score 1):

O Chrome não providencia e nem permite uma forma fácil de desativar http refresh, outro problema é que não é possível 'interceptar' o conteúdo de um request antes que eles sejam renderizados pelo navegador via api.

O refresh por meta-equiv **pode ser desabilitado** [na maioria dos navegadores](http://www.maketecheasier.com/disable-web-page-auto-refresh-for-various-browsers/) por meio de configurações de usuário. Porém o Chrome não. Existe uma [solicitação de correção](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=260831#makechanges) **desde julho/2013** sem  nenhuma atenção. Convoco quem ler isso acessar e votar a favor da implementação.